# Is there any way to view the Console (application output) from the Project view of Xcode?

Tags: xcode

The *All-In-One* variant of **Xcode** operates mostly how I would like my IDE to behave – and with the relatively new and nice inline debugger bar, often my code / fix cycles can be completed within the Project view without switching to the Debug view at all. This is handy because I customize my editors just the way I want and I have the code exactly where I want it and have settled nicely into the context provided by the Project view.

I don't like switching. Switching changes everything around – changes the context – makes me shift out of my state of concentration.

What is annoying is that I have found no way to add the Console output to the Project view.  If I remember correctly, this used to be able to shown in a bottom pane in this view at some point in the past.  Now, I have to switch to Debug view and look at the console output, then switch back to the Project view to look at code and get back into my groove, or just switch to Debug, find my code in it's one editor pane, etc.  This context switching is inefficient and quite disruptive.

Am I missing some easy configuration to get the console into the Project view?

I guess, in the end, I really don't ever want to make these huge context switches (between project / debug) at all, which would be the ultimate solution, but at this point, I'm just hoping that I can get the console window in the Project view.

Comment: I'm starting to think it's not possible... <sigh>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer is the soon to be released [Xcode4](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html) which provides a true all-in-one paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version of Xcode 4 you are running.  But in the latest version that I have, you can see console output in a bottom pane; and you can select debugger or compiler output.

To see the pane, you look at the three-section View icons in the upper right.  Pick the middle one and local variables and the output appear in the editing navigator.  For good measure, punch in all three of those view settings, so you have navigators on the left, utilities on the right and local vars/output on the bottom.

(I'm still trying to wrap my head around schemes, and how to make an actual uploadable archive!)

Comment: Yeah - my question was created long before Xcode4 was announced...  Xcode4 fixes this (see my answer below)